# Windows 8 screen goes black after a minute

Tags: windows-8, display, laptop-display

My laptop screen goes black after about a minute of inactivity.

I've already tried setting the Screen Saver to anything other than *Blank* and increasing the Wait but it still keeps happening.

Also checked my Power Options, the plan I currently have is set to turn the screen off only after an hour.

If I move the mouse or press any key on the keyboard the screen wakes up.

Any other ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Which laptop? there may be hardware settings from BIOS and/or special apps that turns off the backlight (the largest power draw)  Also, unless it's changed in win8, there's two settings: on battery, and plugged in.

Comment: It's a Dell laptop

Comment: See my answer here, it may help http://superuser.com/questions/706237/how-do-delay-the-screen-lock-until-some-time-after-the-screen-turns-off-in-windo/706278#706278

Comment: I don't have Lock Screen settings on my OS, I have Windows 8 not 8.1 maybe that's why

Answer (score 4):

You should set your screen saver to **None** instead of Blank. None maintains the current view. Blank gives you a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

I tried every power setting I could find… twice. I spent hours searching the net and even dug through regedit.  I finally found out it was the darn screen saver.  It alludes me why Microsoft would set the default timeout on the screen saver to 1 minute and the style to blank screen.  Very aggravating.

Comment: This doesn't help me. As stated in the question I've already checked the screen saver settings and it's not the issue

Answer (score 0):

This had been very frustrating for me but I finally found that the default screensaver is blank with a time delay of 1 minute.
Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the Power options in “Advanced” settings tab? If not please try the below mentioned steps:

Click Start button, click Control Panel, click System and Security, and then click Power Options.

On the Select a power plan page, click Change plan settings for the plan that you want to change.

On the Change settings for the plan page, click Change advanced power settings.

On the Advance settings tab, expand Sleep, expand Allow Hybrid Sleep, and choose OFF.

On the Advanced settings tab, expand Sleep, expand Allow wake timers, choose Disable for both when your computer is running on battery and when it's plugged in, and then click OK.

On the Advanced settings tab, expand USB settings, under USB settings expand USB selective suspend settings, choose Disable.

Click Apply and then OK to save the changes.

Check if the above steps work. If all those settings are fine and still the issue persists, this could be malfunction of OS. In such case, performing a Windows Update could help fixing the issue.