# Windows 8 screen goes black after a minute - but I don't have a screensaver

Tags: windows-8, display, screensaver

Similar to [Windows 8 screen goes black after a minute](https://superuser.com/questions/708062/windows-8-screen-goes-black-after-a-minute)

Anyway, I do not have a screen saver set....so...does that mean Windows 8.1, by default blanks out the screen whether a screen saver is set or not?

This is the most annoying advent since, well...since anything.  I can't watch a video, let a web page stay on the screen long enough to read a news item or anything unless I have mouse in hand to keep the screen active.

Microsoft is no help, as they say it is somebody elses software causing the "problem".

Answer (score 1):

*Try this..*

**Go to** 
Control Panel => 
Power Options => 
Change Plan Settings => 
Change Advance Power settings => 
(Scroll Down to) Multimedia settings => 
When Sharing Media => 
(choose) Prevent idling to sleep

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this black screen, please follow the below steps.

1. Check Power Options in Control Panel.
2. From the power option, you can set "Turn off the display".