# How to disable screens turn off Windows 8.1

Tags: display, windows-8.1

So recently my computer started turning my screen monitors off after a while without activity, if I move the mouse or hit the keyboard they turn back on. I just want them to stay on.

My System is windows 8.1 64 bit, I have 2 screens with mini display port and 1 television with hdmi which often is in regular television mode when this issue happens.

Now before you jump to conclusions this is what I've tryed:

- Disabled screen saver
- Power saving settings to high with following
  set:

  - Turn of the display: Never
  - Put the computer to sleep: Never
  - Turn off hard disk after: Settings: Never
  - Sleep: Sleep after: Settings: Never
  - Display: Turn off display after: Settings: Never
  - Display: Enable adaptive brightness: Settings: Off
  - Multimedia settings: When sharing media: Settings: Prevent idling to sleep.

Any pointers that get me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A few things I would try are these: change the settings of Turn off the display after, hit apply, ok. Then change them back to never. Also, I would see if the monitor in question has a setting in its menu to automatically turn it off.

Comment: @LPChip Computer screens doesn't have any settings, TV does. But it's the computer screen which time off (Though I'm not sure they do without the television being turned on). Tryed setting the power settings to on and then off again, will return when I've figured out if this helped and/or if the TV somehow makes the computer screens turn off.

Comment: check this http://superuser.com/questions/706237/delay-the-screen-lock-in-windows-8-1-until-some-time-after-the-screen-turns-off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6e4ca5ef-c483-499c-b68f-856fb68d8867/monitors-turn-off-after-being-locked-for-one-minute?forum=w8itprogeneral) that worked for me. It says:

> at first you must set value of  "Attributes" = dword: 00000002 in [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\8EC4B3A5-6868-48c2-BE75-4F3044BE88A7] ,  and then in  "Power Options" - "Advanced Power Settings" in the "Display" item appears "Console lock display off timeout" in which we set the necessary time.

Hope it helps.