# How to turn off the display while continue working in windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, display

How to keep the display off while working in Windows 10. There are no physical buttons.

So far, the existing [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/801941/how-to-disable-screens-turn-off-windows-8-1) (and answers) require the display to turn on after detecting mouse/keyboard activity. I want to turn on the display manually when required.

It is needed for a visually impaired person who prefers to work without display.

Comment: this seems can be achieved by some third-party application: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-turn-off-screen-of-a-laptop-but-keep-pc-running

Comment: @GloriaGu Unfortunately with all of them the screen turns back on after any key/mouse activity.